# How to update variable values of a powershell script using codedeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm using AWS CodeDeploy and codepipeline for my deployment,and I have a PowerShell script (`bootstrap-base.ps1`) which will be part of ami, resides with-in D:\scripts and I need to update variables of the script during the deployment process. Here's a simplified version of my script:

```
# bootstrap-base.ps1
$bootstrapRepository = "testcd" ;
$environment = "QA" ;

param(
  [String]
  $bootstrapRepository,
  
  [ValidateSet("QA","PROD","PREPROD","TRAIN","DR","OPS", IgnoreCase = $false)]
  [String]
  $environment,

  # Other parameters...
)
# Rest of the script...
```

I need to dynamically update the values of `$bootstrapRepository`and `$environment` during the deployment.
Is there any option to update the values using `appspec.yaml`with AWS CodeDeploy, or do I need to follow a different approach.

how to update PowerShell script variables during an AWS CodeDeploy deployment

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would write the powershell script such that it can work with variables. You can use command line arguments this way -

```
# Access command-line arguments
$env = $args[0] -or "dev"
$ec2ip = $args[1]

Write-Host "environment: $env"
Write-Host "ec2 ip: $ec2ip"
```

And run the script inside my cicd pipeline or where ever you want -

```
powershell script_name.ps1 "stage" "172.168.10.23"
```

Comment: But in my case, script is already part of ami process. Cannot modify it. Only thing I want to do is update the `$bootstrapRepository` and `$environment` variables dynamically. Also I'm using AWS Codedeploy. Any other way to pass these values as inputs and update the existing variables.